# Is there a way to transliterate text in Rules Set a data value?

Tags: 7, rules

I am using rules on a bilingual site. How can I use the "Set a data value" action to set data value of another field using tokens but something like this:

```
$englishKeywords = transliterate([token_name]);
echo $englishKeywords;
```

Where the token name is the field that needs to be transliterated.

Comment: Please add some more details about the code shown, ie what is relevant in it to understand the question entirely? Better still, replace the entire code by actua specs of what exactly you want to do/ask.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I found the answer to my question...do I answer it? My main goal is to transliterate tokens using rules...what rephrasing I should do?

Comment: Yes please post your own answer, and mark it as accepted as soon as you can. But please also address my prior comment, ie edit your question to add more details. And BTW, no need to ask "me" to answer any question. PS after I understand the question, I might upvote it ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens as a beginner I am asking you and I appreciate your time. Let me see how I can be more clear with my question and I will answer it afterwards.

Comment: I think you "***can be more clear***" if you would improve your question as I suggested in my first comment. Ie explain what the code you included is supposed to do, and maybe add an example of what you want to happen. Also, is this about some "path" to be transliterated, or something else?